# Flagging a question to ask a moderator to move my question to another SE site

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819265/unexpected-ads-from-my-website-built-in-codeigniter) thinking that it is for [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) because I've found the right tags which are ads and sql-injection. Due to the comments I realized that it is much better to post this on security.stackexchange.com. **What should I do now?**

So far, I have just flagged it for moderator attention and requested that to be moved to security.stackexchange.com. Is this the right thing to do?

Comment: Aside: This is meta-SO and your question is on SO, [programmers.SE]  is a different SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt your question is a good fit for [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as their on-topic help page states:

> IT Security Stack Exchange is for Information Security professionals to discuss protecting assets from threats and vulnerabilities. Topics include, but are not limited to: web app hardening; network security; social engineering, including phishing; risk management; policies; penetration testing; security tools; using cryptography; incident response; physically securing the office; datacentre; information assets; etc.

From the information in your question it is unclear what the cause of the issues you experience is. To be able to diagnose it needs the code/configuration/setup and an analysis by you of the logfiles and possible causes. At the moment it looks like you expect users to visit your site to do the diagnosis on their own.

As for the flags: Remember that at any time SO moderator have 1000 open flags to handle. It can take a while to handle yours.

As for migration requests in general: They don't go well often basically because of on-topic-ness or quality. You better ask first on the [meta site](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/) to check if the question is on topic there before reposting your question and removing it from SO.

[Obligatory meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites/82986#82986)

Answer (score 11):

Your post is not suitable for any Stack Exchange site, nor for any site on the internet except maybe some recruitment platforms. There is no question in your post. Yes, there are dodgy-looking entries in that list. Yes, they're undoubtedly due to a bug in your code. What do you expect us to do about that? You haven't even posted the code. Looking at the website alone is unlikely to reveal anything.

You're the developer. You need to do your job: debug that code.

If you need **specific** development or debugging help, you can ask on Stack Overflow. Specific means a short, self-contained piece of code, together with a question like “is this code susceptible to SQL injection?” or “how can I do <this task> without risking SQL injection”. If the issue is very specifically about security, Security Stack Exchange might be a better place, but there too you need to have an actual question. Look at the help pages and at existing questions in the relevant tags to get an idea of what questions are suitable.

If you find that you've accidentally posted on the wrong site, as long as your question is unanswered, you can delete it and repost it elsewhere. If your question already has answers or relevant comments, flag it to request a [migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) (your flag should make it clear why the question is off-topic or at least poorly suited where it is now, and why it would be on-topic on the proposed destination). But in this instance, your question is unsuitable anywhere because it isn't in fact a question.

Comment: Does deleting the unanswered question can affect my account and therefore prevent me from asking question?

Comment: @CaryBondoc I don't know the details of the algorithm, but not more than having it deleted later after it's closed, and less than if you wait for it to be downvoted.

Comment: this answer isn't valid in the general sense. its too localized.

Comment: @r3wt Read the last paragraph.

Comment: @Gilles, but that doesn't cover if you've posted and it has already received votes and answers. I asked a bash question on askubuntu earlier today that belonged here, but it received votes and answers. kinda what brought me here. just a small suggestion.

Comment: @r3wt Ok, added a sentence to cover that case.